# clearing the text box after pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, text

i have been trying to clear the text box after pressing the enter key, but i couldn't find any solution for this, been searching for over 2 hours.. this is the code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
input{
margin-top:300px;
margin-left:580px;
}
ul{
margin-left:580px;
}
</style>
<input type="text" id="textBox" value = "" />
<ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
 function addItem(){
        var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
        var candidate = document.getElementById("textBox");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute('id',candidate.value);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById('candidate').value = "";
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = "";
    }
    var input = document.getElementById("textBox");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            addItem();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element whose ID is `candidate` in your HTML code. So JavaScript throws and error and stops executing the next statement. That's why the textbox doesn't clean up.

Remove the buggy statement, and your code works just fine:

```js
function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
  var candidate = document.getElementById("textBox");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id', candidate.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById('textBox').value = "";
}
var input = document.getElementById("textBox");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    addItem();
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textBox" value="" />
<ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>
```